# How to insert into multiple tables on user registration and edit the registration from

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1

How would I insert rows in multiple tables (default User table and Parents table) when registering a new User?
I know I need to edit Models, AuthController and view.

#### My User Model:

```php
namespace Jcfk\Models\User;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function parents() {
        return $this->hasOne("app\Models\Parents");
    }

    /**
     * Is the current user an admin
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAdmin() {
        return $this->role_id === Role::ADMIN;
    }

    public function isParents() {
        return $this->role_id === Role::PARENT;
    }
}
```

#### Parents Model:

```php
namespace Jcfk\Models\Parents;

class Parents extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'parent';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'phone', 'address', 'city_id', 'region',
        'postalcode'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo("app\User");
    }
}
```

#### The Auth Controller:

```php
namespace Jcfk\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Registrar;
use Jcfk\Models\User;
use Jcfk\Models\Parents;
use Validator;
use Jcfk\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data) {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            //'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email'    => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data) {

        $user = new User($data);
        $parents = new Parents($data);
        $user->save();
        $user->Parents()->save($parents);

    }
}
```

The database fields of Parents are `user_id`, `name`, `phone`, `address`, ...
The database fields of User are `user_id`, `email`, `password`, ...

I need help with my `register.blade.php` file as well

```php
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('user_id') }}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Register
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: And what is effect of running the code you have now?

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to achieve. What is a `Parent` and how is it related to a `User`?


Also, you're not doing the Eloquent relationships correctly. For example, the `$this->belongsTo("app\User")` in `Parents::user()` should point to the namespace of User, so `"Jcfk\Models\User"` instead of `"app/User"`. You also need to pass the table names since you're using non-default table names. See the [documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: After reading your question again it seems like you're using `Parents` to hold extra `User` details. Why not just add those fields to the `User` model itself? Then you wouldn't need to worry about Eloquent relationships at all.

Answer (score 10):

Create a service or repository layer.

Create the **repository**:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models\Repositories\User;

use App\Models\Entites\User;
use App\Models\Entites\Parent;

class UserRepository implements UserInterface
{
    public function create($input) 
    {
        $user = new User($data);
        $parents = new Parents($data);
        $user->save();
        $user->Parents()->save($parents);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

This implements an **interface** so we can map the interface to an implementation of it, so it can be injected:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models\Repositories\User;

interface UserInterface
{
    public function create($input); 
}
```

Create a **service provider**, so it can be injected:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models\Repositories\User;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UserRepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    /**
     * Registers the UserInterface with Laravels IoC Container
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Models\Repositories\User\UserInterface', 'App\Models\Repositories\User\UserRepository');
    }
}
```

Add your provider to the `config/app.php` file:

```
    'providers' => [
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Your providers
         */
        App\Models\Repositories\User\UserRepositoryServiceProvider::class,
    ],
```

Now in your controller methods, you can do this:

```
use App\Models\Repositories\User\UserInterface;

protected function create(UserInterface $userRepository, array $data) {
    $userRepository->create($data);
}
```